# How do I open the Document Map in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to quickly browse a Microsoft Word document that contains headings using the Document Map. However, I accidentally closed the Document Map and can't find any way to reopen it.

**How do I open the Document Map in Microsoft Word?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### All versions *except* Word 2007
>
> 1. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

> #### Word 2016, 2013
>
> 1. On the **View** tab, in the **Show** group, select the **Navigation Pane** checkbox.
>
>    [image: Word 2013 - Navigation Pane checkbox]
> 2. On the **Navigation** sidebar, below the search box click **Headings**.
>
>    [image: Word 2013 - Navigation sidebar]

> #### Word 2010
>
> 1. On the **View** tab, in the **Show** group, select the **Navigation Pane** checkbox.
>
>    [image: Word 2010 - Navigation Pane checkbox]
> 2. On the **Navigation** sidebar, below the search box there will be three unlabeled pale buttons. The first one on the left is the Document Map.
>
>    [image: Word 2010 - Navigation sidebar]

> #### Word 2007
>
> 1. On the **View** tab, in the **Show/Hide** group, select the **Document Map** checkbox.
>
>    [image: Word 2007 - Document Map checkbox]

> #### Word 2016 (Mac)
>
> 1. On the **View** menu, click **Draft**, **Web Layout**, **Outline**, or **Print Layout**.
> 2. On the **View** menu, point to **Sidebar**, and then click **Navigation**.

> #### Word 2011 (Mac)
>
> 1. On the **View** menu, click **Draft**, **Web Layout**, **Outline**, or **Print Layout**.
> 2. On the **View** menu, point to **Sidebar**, and then click **Document Map Pane**.

#### Sources

- [Microsoft Support - Navigate in a document by using the Document Map in Word for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Navigate-in-a-document-by-using-the-Document-Map-in-Word-for-Mac-E68FB490-F814-485D-B58B-549ACDE40146)
- [Shauna Kelly - How to use the Document Map in Microsoft Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/documentmap.html)
- [Addintools - Where is Document Map in Word 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016 and Publisher 2010/2013?](http://www.addintools.com/documents/office/where-document-map.html#classicmenu)
- [How-To Geek - Learn How to Use the Document Map in Word 2007](https://www.howtogeek.com/76818/learn-how-to-use-the-document-map-in-word-2007/)
- [Solve Your Tech - How to Open the Navigation Pane in Word 2013](http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-open-the-navigation-pane-in-word-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Office 365, version 16, the answer is **View** menu, click **Navigation Pane**.

To make a shortcut for it, go **Tools** in the top menu bar > Customize Keyboard... > View under Categories > select ViewDocumentMap > assign shortcut.