# Word on Mac: change Navigation Pane DEFAULT to Document Map

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

Microsoft Word for Mac v15.36

There are four options in View - Navigation Pane: Thumbnails Pane, Document Map, Reviewing Pane, and Find and Replace.

[image]

I only need the Document Map (basically table of contents). For some time it is all good: when I open any word doc, the "Document Map" is open by default.

Somehow, the default option became Thumbnails Pane. When I open any word doc, the "Thumbnails Pane" is open, and I need to click the "Document Map" to enable it. Obviously I tried to change this back but not able to. Word keep the "Thumbnails Pane" open by default for EVERY doc!

Can anyone point me on how to change this back? Thanks very much!

Comment: Similar question on Super User [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1238835/how-do-i-open-the-document-map-in-microsoft-word). The keyboard shortcut for Mac is Option+V+D.

Comment: @spike_66 Thanks, but the linked question is about how to open the "Document Map", which is not exactly what I asked. My problem is, when I close Word and open Word again, it changes to open "Thumbnails" instead.

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2007-document-map/84111f60-cb3c-4384-aac6-942ac5a6c715

1. open a single document (default thumbnail view is shown).
2. close the thumbnail view window.
3. close Word.
4. open the document again (no thumbnail should be shown)
5. Now choose View -> Document Map. (the document map is shown).
6. Close Word.
7. Open the document again (the right document map should now be shown)

Comment: thanks @SER. but it seems this doesn't work for me. also, this doc seems to be referring to windows version of office.